# Global CORS errors in Spring API Gateway

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have a webservice for users management that uses Spring security with the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

    // Create AuthenticationFilter
    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = getAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager);

    IpAddressMatcher hasIpAddress = new IpAddressMatcher(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("gateway.ip")));
    IpAddressMatcher hasIpv4Address = new IpAddressMatcher(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("gateway.ipv4")));

    return http
            .cors(corsCustomizer -> corsCustomizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            //.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/**")
                            .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))

                            // on autorise tous les points d'entrée d'actuator
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**"))
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SecurityConstants.EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL)
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_URL)
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_URL)
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    .requestMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello")
                    .access((authentication, context) -> getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address))
                    //.permitAll()
                    //.anyRequest().access((authentication, context) -> {
                    //    if(authentication.get().isAuthenticated())
                    //             return getAccess(authentication, context, hasIpAddress, hasIpv4Address);
                    //    return new AuthorizationDecision(false);
                    //})
            )
            .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, AuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, jwtTokenProvider), AuthorizationFilter.class)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .build();
}
```

On my API gateway, I defined routes and global cors configuration based on [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/cors-configuration.html)  :

```
# https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/cors-configuration.html
spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters= DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations[/**].allowed-origins="http://localhost:4200, http://127.0.0.1:4200"
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations[/**].allowed-headers="*"
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations[/**].allowedMethods="POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations[/**].max-age=3600
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping=true
```

And I defined routes:

```
# user registration routes do not need filter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}


spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id = users-ws-login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# user management routes do  need filter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=users-management-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[1]=Method=GET,PUT,DELETE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[1]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[2]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# configuring filter for actuator
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id = users-ws-actuator
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/actuator/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
```

For security i added the following filter for Authorization:

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationHeaderFilter
        extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthorizationHeaderFilter.Config> {
    private final Environment env;

    // step 1: Reading Authorization HTTP Header
    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationHeaderFilter(Environment env) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.env = env;
    }


    @Override
    //public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        // step 1: Reading Authorization HTTP Header
        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            if(!request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                return onError(exchange, " No authorization Header", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            String authHeader = Objects.requireNonNull(
                    request.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).get((0));
            String jwt = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");

            // step 2: Validating JWT Access Token
            if(!isJwtValid(jwt))
                return onError(exchange, "Invalid JWT", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        });
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, String err, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

    private boolean isJwtValid(String jwt) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        String subject = null;
        String tokenSecret = env.getProperty("token.secret");

        assert tokenSecret != null;
        byte[] tokenSecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(tokenSecret.getBytes());
        SecretKey signingKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(tokenSecretBytes);

        JwtParser parser = Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(signingKey)
                .build();
        try {
            subject = parser.parseSignedClaims(jwt).getPayload().getSubject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            isValid = false;
        }

        if(subject == null || subject.isEmpty()) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return  isValid;
    }

    public static class Config {
        // put configuration properties
    }
}
```

I also tried to configure CORS programmatically :

```
@Configuration
public class AppGlobalCorsConfiguration extends CorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsWebFilter() {
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4200"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
        corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Now here is my issue: the call to login entry point which requires a json payload works fine with Postman but returns CORS error when using an angular application locally.

For login call, I just implemented the following http call :

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<AuthModel>(`${API_USERS_URL}/login`, {
    email,
    password,
  });
}
```

I do have the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using the built in jwt capabillities of spring security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally setting CORS config on your backend controller side should solved you issue:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class AuthController {
  //...
}
```

Comment: very weird but it worked. it seemed i configured correctly my CORS configuration and this annotation should not be required. I tested it using user webservice. I have to do the same using gateway